# how do you connect the data from other table or from the users input on my 5th table?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

- PUTTING DATA ON 5TH TABLE FROM OTHER TABLES OR FROM USERS INPUT
- STORED PROCEDURE FOR INSERTING DATA ON IT

I connected it in my windows form.

Table `supplier`

```
CREATE TABLE SUPPLIER
(
    SUPPLIERID int identity(001,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    SUPPLIERNAME varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ADDRESS varchar(50) NOT NULL,   
    Contact# varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
```

Table `products`:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS
(
    PRODUCTID int identity(301, 1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    PNAME varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PCOLOR varchar(50) 
         FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES PRODUCTCOLOR(PRODUCTCOLOR) NOT NULL,
    PPRICE INT NOT NULL
)
```

Table `productcolor`:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTCOLOR
(   
    PRODUCTCOLOR varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
)
```

Table `customer`:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
(       
    CUSTOMERID int identity(601,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,    
    FIRSTNAME varchar(50) NOT NULL,     
    LASTNAME varchar(50) NOT NULL,                      
    EMAIL varchar(50) NOT NULL ,        
    ADDRESS varchar(50) NOT NULL,       
    TELEPHONE varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    username varchar(50),
    password varchar (50)
)
```

I want to put(connect) them in the 5th table and create a stored procedure with it

Table `orders`:

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS
(
    Cusid int NOT NULL foreign key references CUSTOMER(CUSTOMERID),
    Proid int NOT NULL foreign key references PRODUCTS(PRODUCTID),
    Supp int NOT NULL foreign key references SUPPLIER(SUPPLIERID),
    FNAME VARCHAR(50),
    LNAME VARCHAR(50),
    PRONAME VARCHAR(50),
    SUPNAME VARCHAR(50),
    PCOLOR  varchar(50)FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES PRODUCTCOLOR(PRODUCTCOLOR)NOT NULL,
    QUANTITY VARCHAR(50)primary key NOT NULL
)
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_order
    @FNAME varchar(50),         
    @LNAME varchar(50),                     
    @PRONAME varchar(50),       
    @SUPNAME varchar(50),       
    @PCOLOR varchar(50),
    @QUANTITY int
AS
    INSERT INTO ORDERS 
    VALUES (@FNAME, @LNAME, @PRONAME, @SUPNAME, @PCOLOR, @QUANTITY)

    RETURN 0
```

I don't know if my 5th table is right and my stored procedure.

I've tried many things but it's kinda confusing

Comment: Nobody but you can know if your table is "right" except you, but I can say that you cannot insert into it without providing values for the `NOT NULL` columns.

Comment: my stored procedure got this error so i know somethings not right
 `Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.` @Crowcoder

Comment: In you want to insert you need to supply CustId,ProdId and Supp also in your insert statement.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not inserting into ALL columns of a table then the INSERT statement must list the specific columns:

```
INSERT INTO ORDERS (FNAME, LNAME, PRONAME, SUPNAME, PCOLOR, QUANTITY)
VALUES(@FNAME,@LNAME,@PRONAME , @SUPNAME, @PCOLOR, @QUANTITY);
```

Notice how the column names are specified *and also* the values are provided.

**However**, your table has defined `NOT NULL` columns so you must provide values for those.

Your procedure should look more like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_order
@Cusid int,
@Proid int,
@Supp int,
@FNAME varchar(50),         
@LNAME varchar(50),                     
@PRONAME varchar(50),       
@SUPNAME varchar(50),       
@PCOLOR varchar(50),
@QUANTITY int
AS

    INSERT INTO ORDERS (Cusid, Proid, Supp, FNAME, LNAME, PRONAME, SUPNAME, PCOLOR, QUANTITY)
    VALUES(@Cusid, @Proid, @Supp, @FNAME,@LNAME,@PRONAME , @SUPNAME, @PCOLOR, @QUANTITY);

RETURN 0;
```

Now you have the issue about obtaining the values for those foreign keys. I can't help with that based on the information you have provided.

*as an aside* you shouldn't name procedures with "sp_" because that is a special prefix that will hit you with a small performance penalty.

Comment: how do i obtain the values of other tables ? all tables except table order already has values in it
for example the fname and lname i want to get the values from the table customer using the procedure to insert in table orders



        _thanks your awsome_ ☺

Comment: You will have to obtain them from the UI, like from combo box controls or listbox or something. I can't be specific but it would be very similar to how you obtain any value except usually foreign key data is given in some kind of pick list.